# Freshwater aquarium - many fish batches dead, LFS keeps claiming that water is 'perfect'

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater

Got a new 30 gallon aquarium ~1 month ago.
The seller told me to use tap water (no conditiner), run the pump for a week (to get rid of chlorine), then bring a sample for test.

Did that, didn't use any soap/detergents for cleaning. All the rock/plants are from the same LFS.

One week later, brought the water sample for test, they said 'perfect' (1), gave me 6 tetra pristellas. Dummy me, came home, dumped everything in the aquarium.

One week later, 4 out of 6 still alive, another water sample, another 'perfect' (2) from LFS, a new group of fish (mollies, guppy, 1 gourami, 2 plecos - 9 total). Dumped them all again (really stupid). Mollies were really happy initially, one of them even gave birth.

Another week later, 9 fish dead, coming sad to the LFS, with another water sample, another 'perfect' (3). This time they sold me another 5 tetras (the remaining tetra 'is very sad, let's add compay') as well as 3 otocinclus, to keep raving algae in control. This time I made sure that the bag temperature is same as in aquarium, did partial water changes in the bag, topping it with the aquarium water. About ~45 minutes before releasing them.

Another week later, 4 tetra and 1 oto dead. Come to the same LFS, the water is 'perfect' (4) again, they even tested for P, PB and copper. Nothing. The readings were as previous: 
Nitrate < 5, Nitrite = 0, Total hardness - hard, Total chlorine - 0, KH - 40, pH - ~7.4.

Besides this, I have a liquid test at home, pH is always ~ 7.4, amonia/Nitrate/Nitrite - lowest value on the charts.

So, now I have 2 tetras and 2 oto, still alive but not very happy. Pump is rated for 50 gallons, always running. Temperature measured by 2 different thermometers - 79, maintained by 2 heaters rated for 25 gallons.

Sorry for long preamble - but what should I do now? I finally conditioned full aquarium (using stuff that's sold by LFS), thinking about getting a RODI filter - maybe the tap water has something not showing on the tests? Paying $250 for a full water test is a bit expensive.

P.S. Fish was always fed once a day, but all of them stopped eating after a days or two.

Comment: Yes, the pump has filter, with carbon and media for bacteria to grow. I think the main problem is that not enough bacteria grew up before adding new fish. Some resources say that the cycle takes 4-6 weeks, not one...

Comment: The root cause turns out to be faulty liquid test solution for Ammonia. It shows only 2 ppm in a 50/50 mix of water with household ammonia :)

Comment: Your water utility probably uses chloramines and not chlorine for treatment. You must treat the water to remove chloramines, they are stable and do not dissipate on their own. What filtration do you have in this tank? Generally, in a situation like yours, I suggest just not messing with anything for some time and see what happens. Since none of the measurements you're getting are showing a problem, don't try to correct anything, because you don't know what it is. No reason you should need to get a RO/DI unit with your setup. Way overkill.

Comment: @StKiller if you have found the reason for your problem,you can answer your own question,you will get some additional points and our site will have one less un answered question :)